# vue.js how to create a route poiting to a XML file instade of .vue

Tags: xml, vue.js, vue-router, sitemap, google-search-console

I'm trying to figure out how can I create a route pointing to a xml file using vue-router. Actually I need this because I need to set a sitemap.xml at Google search console:

[image]

As you can see, Google request a url from my website with .xml extension file.

I've searched everywhere I can't find a away to create a .xml url with vuejs using, for instance, vue-router. Here are my routes using vue-router, of course every route is a .vue file now:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import Home from '../views/Home.vue'
import NotFound from '../views/NotFound'
import CreateProject from '../views/LeadForm'
import BusinessCustomer from '../views/BusinessCustomer'

Vue.use(VueRouter)


const routes = [{
        path: '/',
        name: 'Home',
        component: Home,
    },
    {
        path: '/projeto/criar',
        name: 'CreateProject',
        component: CreateProject
    },
    {
        path: '/projeto/criar/:token',
        name: 'BusinessCustomer',
        component: BusinessCustomer
    },

    {
        path: '*',
        name: "404",
        component: NotFound
    }

]

const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    base: process.env.BASE_URL,
    routes
})

export default router
```

And here is my sitemap.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">

   <url>

      <loc>https://www.gorilafreela.com.br/</loc>

      <lastmod>2022-01-25</lastmod>

      <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>

      <priority>0.8</priority>

   </url>
   <url>

      <loc>https://gorilafreela.com.br/projeto/criar</loc>

      <lastmod>2022-01-25</lastmod>

      <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>

      <priority>0.6</priority>

   </url>

</urlset>
```

Anyone have any ideia how can I solve this issue, how can I create a route linking to my sitemap.xml to provide to Google search console. I haven't fund a solution to this issue on the internet. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why do you need router for this? Vue router is client side only. Ideally you don't want Google bot to run your Vue app. Just create a static `sitemap.xml` and place it into public directory of your web server next to `index.html`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use vue router to do this. Just drop the sitemap.xml file into your public folder. You should then be able to see the sitemap at /sitemap.xml